How to Modify SPEPTR Script in Sage X3 to Include All Dock Locations Regardless of Category
`I am working on customizing the SPEPTR script in Sage X3. I need to modify it so that the dock location (emplacement quai) selection includes all locations from any category, not just those in the 'waiting for storage' category. Could anyone guide me on how to implement this in the script?
`

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is the list concerning SageMath, not Sage X3. Please look for a different tag.
